# ModelState invalid for decimal (2000.00)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm having trouble validating 1 instance of my model `medewerker_functie`.

In that Model I have 3 instances that are decimals, 2 of them are being validated while `Salary` isn't.

The 3 instances are `uren` which is 40.0, `fulltime_salaris` which is 2200.00, `salaris` which is 2000.00.

In my `Actionresult Create` I get those values as strings, the reason of that is I get the value from a field with JavaScript: upon filling in the `salaris` input field:

```
onblur="$(this).val(parseFloat($(this).val()).toFixed(2))"
```

for display purposes.

And then just before the AJAX call, I get the values using jQuery and thought I'd try and make it a number type value so I did another `parseFloat(2000.00).toFixed(2)` but that just keeps it as a string and doesn't change the value.

This is my `ActionResult Create`:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,medID,functieID,type_contract,startdatum,einddatum,aantal_uur,aantal_dagen,fulltime_salaris,salaris")] medewerker_functie medewerker_functie, int medID, int functieID, string contract, DateTime startDate, DateTime? endDate, String uren, int dagen, String fulltime, String salaris)
{

    System.Globalization.CultureInfo culInfo = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-EN", false);

    decimal dec_uren = Convert.ToDecimal(uren.Replace('.', ','), culInfo);
    decimal dec_fulltime = Convert.ToDecimal(fulltime.Replace('.', ','), culInfo);
    decimal dec_salaris = Convert.ToDecimal(salaris.Replace('.', ','), culInfo);

    //Vervang decimaal punten met comma's
    //uren = uren.Replace('.', ',');
    //fulltime = fulltime.Replace('.', ',');
    //salaris = salaris.Replace('.', ',');

    //decimal dec_uren = Convert.ToDecimal(uren);
    //decimal dec_fulltime = Convert.ToDecimal(fulltime);
    //decimal dec_salaris = Convert.ToDecimal(salaris);

    //vull medewerker_functie met waardes
    medewerker_functie.medID = medID;
    medewerker_functie.functieID = functieID;
    medewerker_functie.type_contract = contract;
    medewerker_functie.startdatum = startDate;
    medewerker_functie.einddatum = endDate;
    medewerker_functie.aantal_dagen = dagen;

    //These are the fields in question but mostly just salaris.
    medewerker_functie.aantal_uur = dec_uren;
    medewerker_functie.fulltime_salaris = dec_fulltime;
    //medewerker_functie.salaris = Convert.ToDecimal(salaris);
    medewerker_functie.salaris = dec_salaris;

    if (ModelState.IsValid) //The value '2000.00' is not valid for salaris
    {
        db.medewerker_functie.Add(medewerker_functie);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Details", "medewerker");
    }

    ViewBag.functieID = new SelectList(db.functie, "ID", "Functie1", medewerker_functie.functieID);
    ViewBag.medID = new SelectList(db.medewerker, "ID", "roepnaam", medewerker_functie.medID);
    return View(medewerker_functie);
}
```

In my model they're also specified as decimal:

```
public decimal aantal_uur { get; set; }
public Nullable<decimal> fulltime_salaris { get; set; }
public Nullable<decimal> salaris { get; set; }
```

Also my globalization is set to `nl-NL`:

```
<globalization culture="nl-NL" uiCulture="nl-NL"/>
```

I've tried converting to decimal with `culInfo` and without, with replacing, to `.` and the other way around and without, but none of it seems to be working, any thoughts?

But what's even more confusing to me is that it does accept 2200.00 for `fulltime_salaris` and 40.0 for `uren`.

Oh and in my database the fields are also specified as `decimal(18,2)`;

And I figured I'd mention it was quite the search for the error because it was nearly buried, but this is where I found the error:

[image: showing error in debugger mode]

---

**EDIT**

This is the AJAX call:

```
console.log(uren, fullTime, salaris); //returns 40.0, 2200.00, 2000.00
console.log($.type(uren), $.type(fullTime), $.type(salaris)); // returns string, string, string

var floatUren = parseFloat(uren).toFixed(1);
var floatFullTime = parseFloat(fullTime).toFixed(2);
var floatSalaris = parseFloat(salaris).toFixed(2);

console.log(floatUren, floatFullTime, floatSalaris); //returns 40.0, 2200.00, 2000.00
console.log($.type(floatUren), $.type(floatFullTime), $.type(floatSalaris)); // returns string, string, string

var form = $('#__AjaxAntiForgeryForm');
var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]', form).val();
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: '@Url.Action("Create", "medewerker_functie")',
  data: {
    __RequestVerificationToken: token,
    medID: medewerker,
    functieID: functie,
    contract: contract,
    startDate: startDate,
    endDate: endDate,
    uren: floatUren,
    dagen: dagen,
    fullTime: floatFullTime,
    salarispara: floatSalaris
  },
  success: function() {
    alert('Succes!');
  },
  error: function() {
    alert('Failure!');
  }
});
```

Comment: Sounds like you need a customized model binder to be able using different separators, because `toFixed` method will return numeric value with decimal point as separator regardless of current culture settings.

Comment: strange.. tho immediately after this post, I changed the paramater salary it salaryPara to see if there was any name conflict. and now the `ModelState.isValid` returns `true`... but my ajax call still throws an `error` instead of `succes`

Comment: If the AJAX callback results going to `error` part, there should be something went wrong when providing passed data. Can you provide some clues which kind of AJAX callback being used to pass decimal values?

Comment: let me update the question, give me 5 minutes

Comment: I would also like to share the table in which the fields are but that's being built using a bunch of variables and is set up in parts so that's hard to read unless I give you everything and you have to glue pieces together yourself. but this is the salary input `<input id="inputSalaris" ' + onSalarisBlur + ' name="inputSalaris" style=' + numberfieldStyle + ' type="number" min="0.00" step="any" />`...  `onSalarisBlur` is `onblur="$(this).val(parseFloat($(this).val()).toFixed(2))"` and `numberFieldStyle` is just `css`

Comment: oh actually I solved it changing the name of the parameter. it was just throwing an error on my redirectToAction... my bad hahaha

Comment: `String salaris` => `String salarispara`, right? I already seen that you've parameter mismatch between AJAX callback and POST action method, but `RedirectToAction` issue seems to be different one.

Comment: the RedirectToAction was because I was redirecting to an Action that required an ID parameter which I forgot to specify.

Yeah `String salaris` => `String salarispara` but that's just cause I forgot to change that in the question. in my code it's both salarispara now, in both ajax and controller

Answer (score 0):

The fix was changing the name of the parameter `String salaris`. I can only assume it was conflicting with the Bind parameter `Salaris` so I was placing `dec_salaris` in the Model but the `ModelState.IsValid` was checking on the `Bind param Salaris` which was still a `string`, thus invalid..

Thanks everyone for your assistance x)